# Obtener valores seleccionados de arreglo de checkbox, y de arreglo de inputs a través de bucles. Para ejecutar una consulta con los valores obtenidos

Tags: php, mysqli

En este código intento obtener valores de `checkbox` seleccionados, dentro de un bucle, y en otro bucle anidado se obtienen valores de `inputs` fijos.
Con estos valores iterados obtenidos dentro de los bucles buscaba ejecutar un `delete` poniendo como parametros `where` los valores de cada `alumno` seleccionado y los `grupos` que son valores de inputs ya predefinidos. 
Intentaba que se ejecutara el `query` con los valores de n `checkbox` que se hayan seleccionado y con sus respectivos grupos, pero no alcanza a ejecutarlo para todos los registros encontrados, me parece es error de lógica en los bucles.

El problema es que la sentencia no se ejecuta para todos los valores `checkbox` seleccionados. Por ejemplo si se seleccionaron 40, el delete solo se ejecuta para 34,

```js
 $alumno     = $_POST["idalumno"]; //arreglo [] de alumnos (recogiendo id de arreglo de checkbox)
  $idgrupo    = $_POST["idgrupo"]; //arreglo [] de grupos, inputs (hidden)

  for ($i=0; $i < count($alumno); $i++) { //mientras la variable sea menor al tamaño de arreglo va aumentando de uno en uno

       $alum = $alumno[$i]; //obteniendo cada idalumno

       for ($a=0; $a < count($idgrupo); $a++) {

             $gpo = $idgrupo[$a]; //obteniendo id de cada grupo

       $verifica = "SELECT * FROM alumno_grupo WHERE idAlumno = '{$alum}' and idGrupo = '{$gpo}'";
       $consul = mysqli_query($conexion, $verifica)or die (mysqli_error($conexion)); 
       $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($consul);
       if ($num_rows > 0) {

       $cons = "DELETE FROM alumno_grupo WHERE idAlumno = '{$alum}' AND idGrupo = '{$gpo}'";  

       $consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, $cons)or die (mysqli_error($conexion));  

       if ($consulta){
  ?>
   <script>
   alert('ALUMNO DADO DE BAJA DE LOS GRUPOS-MATERIA, CORRECTAMENTE')
   location.href = "../View/Admin/baja_alum.php"; 
   </script>

  <?php
  } else {  //si no se ejecuta la consulta
  ?>
   <script>
   alert('ATENCION !!!! ERROR AL ELIMINAR')
   location.href = "../View/Admin/baja_alum.php"; 
   </script>

  <?php
  }
       } else {  //si no se encuentran los registros
       ?>

      <script>
       alert('ATENCIÓN!!: NO SE ENCONTRO REGISTRO CON ESE ALUMNO Y GRUPO-MATERIA')
       location.href = "../View/Admin/baja_alum.php"; 
      </script>

       <?php
       } //else
    } //for
  } //for
```

Comment: Pero te da un error?

Comment: Cual es el problema puntual?

Comment: La accion del query: delete, no se ejecuta para todos los valores del arreglo checkbox seleccionados, por ejemplo si se seleccionan 40 checkbox solo se hace la eliminacion de 35, en los bucles creo que no alcanzan a pasar todos los idalumno seleccionados

Answer (score 1):

mejor con un prepare para la eliminación y un query para la consulta

```
   $conexion = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
   for ($i=0; $i < count($alumno); $i++) { //mientras la variable sea menor al tamaño de arreglo va aumentando de uno en uno

       $alum = $alumno[$i]; //obteniendo cada idalumno

       for ($a=0; $a < count($idgrupo); $a++) {

          $gpo = $idgrupo[$a]; //obteniendo id de cada grupo

          $resultado = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM alumno_grupo WHERE idAlumno = '{$alum}' and idGrupo = '{$gpo}'");
          if ( $resultado->num_rows > 0){

              $sth = $conexion->prepare("DELETE FROM alumno_grupo WHERE idAlumno = ? AND idGrupo = ?);  
              $sth->bind_param("ii", $alum, $gpo); //i para integer , s para string
              if ($sth->execute()){
                 //codigo script
              }else{
              //codigo script

             }
         } else {
    }
```

Comment: gracias, saludos:
sigue eliminando igual solo una parte de los ids seleccionados, y manda este error: Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded
en la linea del execute,

Comment: Coloca más tiempo de ejecución a tu servidor

Comment: de acuerdo,  ¿como se debe hacer? probaré. gracias

Answer (score 1):

Puede ser un problema tanto de diseño como del bucle. Sugiero que antes de cualquier cosa revises que tienes las mismas llaves en los dos arrays, de ser así entonces usa lo siguiente:

Probablemente sea buena idea escapar todos los grupos y alumnos si son string, puedes usar algo así:

```
array_walk($idgrupo, function(&$value, &$key) {
  $value = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $value);
});
```

Luego ya podemos hacer el loop:

```
$alumno     = $_POST["idalumno"]; //por si falta...
$idgrupo    = $_POST["idgrupo"];
$array_final = [];
foreach($alumno AS $id => $nombre){      
   $array_final[] = (mysqli_query($conexion, "DELETE FROM alumno_grupo WHERE idAlumno = '{$id}' AND idGrupo IN (".implode(',', $idgrupo).")") ? "El alumno $nombre Se ha borrado de todos los grupos seleccionados." : "Hay un error");
}
```

El Javascript de abajo va a imprimir lo que le mandemos... no es necesario mandar 5000 alerts + 5000 `<script>`

```
echo '<script>
 alert('.implode("\n", $array_final).');
 location.href = "../View/Admin/baja_alum.php"; 
</script>';
```

Comment: idgrupos e idalumnos son numéricos,  Ya no se deben escapar entonces?

Comment: No es necesario escaparlos, solo implotarlos e incluirlos en la clausula `IN ()`, espero esto resuelva tu problema.

Comment: voy a probarlo, gracias, disculpa pero creo que le hace falta un paréntesis

Comment: De hecho un paréntesis y un punto y coma :)  ¡gracias! ya está editado.

Comment: gracias, saludos. parece que no realiza la sentencia sql, no ejecuta nada

Comment: ¿Regresa algo en el `$array_final`? La única forma de que no ejecute es que `$alumno` esté vacío.

Comment: puede ser, pero probe ejecutando el código que tenia primero, y recibe los valores, no están vacios

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51215/discussion-between-solrac-ragnarockradio-and-armando-arellano).

Answer (score 1):

Puedes intentar esto en tu javascript:

```
var seleccionados = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function() {
            return this.value;
        }).get();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'accione.php',
            data: { arreglo : seleccionados },
            // seleecionados= [id,id,id,id,id...]

        });
```

y tu php:

```
 $data = $_POST["arreglo"];
   foreach($data as $alumno){
                $sql = "delete from tabla where group_id ='".$alumno."'";
    mysqli_query($cx,$sql);
        }
```